# Looking for obsolete "libGLcore.so.1"

Tags: debian, libraries, nvidia, opengl, steam

I've installed Steam on Debian using the [Steam Wheezy Installer](https://github.com/GhostSquad57/Steam-Installer-for-Wheezy). On start up it says it's missing the 32-bit library `libGLcore.so.1`. Doing a [package search](https://packages.debian.org/cgi-bin/search_contents.pl?word=libGLcore.so&searchmode=searchfiles&case=insensitive&version=unstable&arch=i386) I find it only exists in old nVidia drivers, whereas I'm currently running the 300 series driver. Why is Steam looking for an ancient library unrelated to the one I've been running for years and is there anything I can do to fix it?